# React Native <Text> breaks out of Flexbox layout

Tags: react-native, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to create a simple layout using Flexbox in React Native. I want to have a row that takes up the width of the screen. Inside the row there are icons on the left and right and then text that takes up the remaining space in the middle of the row. I'm setting `flexGrow:1` on the middle content, but the text is expanding beyond the width constraints of the row. How can I modify the code to get the desired layout?

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const Flex = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <View style={styles.icon}/>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text numberOfLines={2}>
          I want to truncate this text
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.icon}/>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    width: '100%',    
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginHorizontal: 12,
    padding: 24,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
  },
  icon: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height: 56,
    width: 56,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: 4,
  }
});
```

[Link to Expo](https://snack.expo.io/-e8b9fjrK)

Comment: use `flex: 1` instead of `flexGrow: 1`

Comment: Thank you! I had to add `flex:1` and `flexGrow:1` and that resolved my issue. Appreciate the help!